# How can I impersonate the calling user for a COM object?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, com

I have IIS 6.0, mvc 3 application running under asp .net 4.0,
basic authentication, web.config has

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

I need to use IPersistFile to access my file.
The problem is that COM runs under NETWORK SERVICE account and I don't want to give permissions to the file for the NETWORK SERVICE.
So, how can I impersonate the calling user for a COM object?

Comment: Solved.You need to call COM object in a separate STA thread.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325791/en-us?fr=1

Comment: you should post your comment as an answer so others can find it useful.  Its ok to answer your own question here.

Comment: Yeah, I know but there is a time limit so you can't answer you own question in 8 hours (or something near this).

Answer (score 1):

> ### Answer as discovered by origional poster

Solved.

You need to call COM object in a separate STA thread.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325791/en-us?fr=1